# JSF SelectOneMenu with a Object Converter and null ids

Tags: jsf-2

okay lets start step by step:
Imagin, you have a selectOneMenu component which is working with objects which are comming from the database.

To work with objects in a selectOneMenu component, you have to define a simple converter which compare the object id with the givin string value which is passed as a function parameter and return the correct object. So far so good, nothing special here.

Now, a user can add additional Objects, which will be added to the selectOneMenu component.
The problem is now, if the user select the selfdefined object in the selectOneMenu component, it will throw an error, because of id is null. A workaround is to give the manual added object (created by a user) a unique id, and all is fine. But does exist a solution where no ids are required and still working with objects ?

thanks

Comment: Sure, the solution exists and depends on how you have implemented what you have described. Show some code.

Comment: Got it working, sometimes people should think out of the box :) Had to use hashcode instead of the id, which will be normaly used to identified a unique object. getAsString returns the hash and on getAsObject compare the passed parameter hashcode with the objects in the list. All is working fine now, but thanks for your time